# Use of don't and doesn't

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, objects

In the following sentence which is correct, and why?

As homeschool moms, we know there (don't/doesn't) seem to be enough hours in the day to tackle all that we want to teach our girls.

Answer (score 0):

> we know there **don't seem** to be enough hours in the day

Let's look for the subject of *don't seem*.  It's obviously not "We" or "day," so logically, it has to be "hours."

Since *hours* is plural, you would say "The hours *don't seem* to be passing quickly enough today."

Comment: In addition to the fact that "hours" is plural, one needs to realize that, despite its location in the sentence, "hours" is the subject of the verb phrase "don't seem".  I suspect this realization is what the OP was missing.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - Thanks for the suggestion.  I've edited my answer.